# View Modern Page Draft From Another User

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, collaboration, draft

A user and I are collaborating on modern page changes to a specific news article on our Intranet in SharePoint Online. We are both admins of this site collection. Is there a way I can see his drafted changes without him having to Republish the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, we could view modern page draf from other users as site collection admins.

Besides, you could specify which users should be able to view drafts in  document library in Library settings-> Version Settings. As the below picture shows:

[image]